# Compass Create Options

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I've installed Compass via Ruby Gems. When I create a new project it creates:

- config.rb
- /sass
- /stylesheet

Is it possible to use my existing directories? For example I am using a PHP Framework, that has a /css directory, and ideally I'd like to use that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [Compass Configuration Reference](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/):

You can change the default CSS directory by changing this in `config.rb`:

```
css_dir = "css"
```